# I want to change data item per row in Mobile view via jquery script

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, mobile, squarespace

I'm using squarespace for designing website. Currently, in squarespace default template the data-item-per-row is set as 3. Please see this below screenshot of the code marked as red.

[image]

The place where you see "data-item-per-row="3"" I want that to be change to ""data-item-per-row="1"", just for mobile view using jquery script if possible?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example This can be done using `.data("items-per-row", 1)` yet you need the right selector. Off the cuff, this would be `$(".Production-grid")`, but it's not clear if this the only element with that class.

Answer (score 0):

As it happens, JavaScript/JQuery aren't necessary to achieve a single column of products on mobile. In fact, if you did update this data attribute value but did nothing else, it would have no effect. You would also have to reinitialize the product grid, which could prove to be unnecessarily time consuming.

Instead, simply use CSS, inserted via [Custom CSS](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .ProductList-item {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

The value of `640px` is the default "mobile" breakpoint on [Brine-based Squarespace templates](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/212512738-Brine-template-family), which may well be what you are using. You can adjust that value in the CSS above to your liking.